# How to make the image as default using image-picker.js?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i'm using image-picker.js
How to make the image as default?

```
<!-- / select number of pet-->
<div class="select-pets text-center">

     <p>Select Your Pet</p>
      <div>

<select multiple="multiple" class="image-picker show-labels show-html">

 <option data-img-src="assets/img/pets/cat1.png" data-img-class="first" data-img-alt="Ricky" value="1" class="stretched-link ">  Ricky  </option>

</select>


</div>

</div>
<!--/ select number of pet -->
```

https://rvera.github.io/image-picker/

[before tick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7jAo.png)

[after tick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wE07x.png)